# Calling a stored procedure in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have created few stored procedures in MySql, using the commands

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sample() 
BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM members; 
END //
```

But when i want to cal a stored procedure in my phpMyAdmin or using php i am not getting the result.Commands i used

```
CALL sample;
```

and also

```
 CALL sample();
```

When i use he above query no output is shown instead page is redirected to phpMyAdmin home page . 
Do i need to make any changes in phpMyAdmin???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure is most probably not being created.

You must include the `DELIMITER` command to tell MySQL to ignore the `;` in your command:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE sample()
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM members;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

That tells MySQL to use a different delimiter (`//` in this case) and restore it (the standard `;` delimiter) at the end of the query.

Then, check your procedure exists with `SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS`.

As far as I know, you shouldn't need the brackets `()` to call a procedure that doesn't require any arguments.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks jonathan.....Yes SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS is working and its showing two procedures that i have created, but when i CALL them nothing is displayed

Comment: Check permissions (I think you need "Execute"), check MySQL version, try with diff MySQL client, and obviously, make sure the query works on its own... Let us know!

Answer (score 2):

use `()` for calling stored procedure

```
CALL sample();
```

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,358569

you missed the DELIMITER

```
 DELIMITER // 
 CREATE PROCEDURE sample() 
 BEGIN 
 SELECT * FROM members; 
 END // 
 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: do i need to make any changes in phpMyAdmin ??

Comment: @PavanK i edited the answer and checked the query now its creating stored procedure and calling also.

Comment: still i am nt able to call stored procedure, i guess problem may be with my phpMyAdmin

Comment: @PavanK I tried the same code which I written is working on my end.Don't what is the problem at your end.